# powershell creating excel file

Tags: excel, powershell

I am confused what I am doing wrong.

Every time in PowerShell I create an excel file, it opens excel.  Then it Places the data into excel.  However when it goes to save excel file,  then closes excel.   The file I try to open says it is corrupted or not in the correct format to open.
Can I get some guidance please?  I would like to save in xlsx format if possible, but will settle for xls.

```
$SaveAsPathFinal = "C:\Temp\myfile.xlsx"
 $Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
$xlFixedFormat = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat]::xlOpenXMLWorkbook

$Excel.Visible = $True
$Excel = $Excel.Workbooks.Add()
$Sheet = $Excel.Worksheets.Item(1)
$Sheet.Name = "Printer Inventory"
#======================================================
$Sheet.Cells.Item(1,1) = "Print Server"
$Sheet.Cells.Item(1,2) = "Printer Name"

#=======================================================
$intRow = 2
$WorkBook = $Sheet.UsedRange
$WorkBook.Interior.ColorIndex = 40
$WorkBook.Font.ColorIndex = 11
$WorkBook.Font.Bold = $True
$PrintServerCounter = 0
#=======================================================


foreach ($PrinterInfo in $Script:Jobs_PrinterInfo)
{
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow, 1) = $PrinterInfo.Server
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow, 2) = $PrinterInfo.Name
$intRow ++  #move to the next in excel
}


$WorkBook.EntireColumn.AutoFit() | Out-Null

$intRow ++ 
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,1) = "Printer inventory completed"
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,1).Font.Bold = $True
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,1).Interior.ColorIndex = 40
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,2).Interior.ColorIndex = 40
Write-Verbose "$(Get-Date): Completed!"
#   This like is commented out # $xlFixedFormat = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat]::xlWorkbookDefault
$Excel = $Excel.SaveAs("$SaveAsPathFinal”,1)
$Excel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs($SaveAsPathFinal, $xlFixedFormat)
$Excel.Saved = $True
if ($CloseReportFile)
{
    $Excel.Close()
}
```

Comment: Exact Error: Excel cannot open the file "<FILENAME>.xlsx" because the file format or file extension is not valid.  Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.

Comment: ```#$xlFixedFormat = …``` - is this a typo, or is this line commented out in your original code as well? The variable is used in the next line, so is equivalent to ```… SaveAs($SaveAsPathFinal, $null)``` which *could* be the source of the problem…

Comment: Where is `$SaveAsPathFinal` defined and you should not use curly so-called smart-quotes in code. Especially do not mix these with regular quotes as you do here: `$Excel = $Excel.SaveAs("$SaveAsPathFinal”,1)`

Comment: I have updated the code  Yes #$xlFixedFormat = … is commented out.  it is referenced at the top of the script.